# Question regarding package management in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been using PyCharm since I began learning Python because of its amazing UI that helped me learn a great deal about the language. As I progress into more advanced projects, I am beginning to prefer using a text editor / command line combo so that I can build my own venv's and have better access to source control. My question is, how does PyCharm manage custom local packages that I created so that I can import them wherever I want in the directory? For instance a project that I have built exclusively in PyCharm that runs will raise numerous import errors when trying to run that same project in VS code, or even a command line shell (yes I did have the PyCharm created venv activated before running on both attempts). For further examples, here is the project structure I am confused about:

```
RootDirectory
    package_1_folder
        __init__.py
        pckg_1_class.py
    program_using_pckg_1_folder
        class_using_pckg1class.py
    venv
```

The above structure has no issues being imported and used in PyCharm, however VS code / Sublime when used with command prompt / gitbash will raise either an ImportError or a ModuleNotFound error. I have even gone as far as adding the desired packages to my laptops windows PATH, using sys.path.append (I know this is not good practice I was only trying to get it to work), and even modified the .pylintrc file with the project path with no success. Any help explaining why these errors are happening would be greatly appreciated :)

NOTE:
I have been able to use the packages in VS code as long as the program importing the module is located at the root directory level, but not in its own folder in the root directory. Again, this statement WILL work in PyCharm, I just want to know how PyCharm is able to achieve this.

Comment: If you run `python class_using_pckg1class.py` in `program_using_pckg_1_folder` then that's the problem.

Comment: But if you run `python program_using_pckg_1_folder/class_using_pckg1class.py` from `RootDirectory` and still get error then I have no idea.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I am currently trying to run a program using the first way you described, I understand that your second comment works. My question is, why does the first action you described compile in PyCharm?

Comment: It shouldn't. If you press run button in Pycharm it runs something similar to my second comment. The first comment shouldn't work because there's no `package_1_folder` in `program_using_pckg_1_folder`. If that runs then it's weird.

Comment: PyCharm does `sys.path.extend` to add the locations it needs. If you run it in the PyCharm Console you can see what it adds and copy it into your script.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts to locate how the system was keeping tack of module within the IDE, I found that my answer was not visible from the IDE. I found a .idea folder in my root directory that contains a few .xml documents that manage the directory including where to read modules from.